# Linq Enumerable.Where Func not getting called

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have the following code

```
var filteredList = posData.Where(x => MyFilter(x, ruleDetail.wheres)).ToList();
```

where MyFilter is defined as

```
    static bool MyFilter(Dictionary<string,string> dict, List<WhereClause> wheres)
    {
        if (dict["x"] == "y")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

posData is of type

```
List<dictionary<string,string>>
```

I have a breakpoint in MyFilter function but the code execution never gets there. I am looking for MyFilter to do some custom analysis based on the wheres parameter. This is only a small part of the code. Please help me figure out why is MyFilter not getting called ?

Comment: Is the `postData` a collection of `Dictionary<string, string>`?

Comment: As an aside, the body of you method can be replaced with just: `return dict["x"] == "y";`

Comment: Maybe `posData` is empty? That would prevent `MyFilter()` from being called.

Comment: posData isn't empty. Its a List<Dictionary<string,string>> and has Count() > 0

Comment: @FelipeOriani yes

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine and as expected. The only reason that it wouldn't work in your case is if `posData` is empty, **so make sure that it's not**.

I tried it with this code *(which is basically the same as yours)*:

```
static void Main()
{
    // create test collection
    var posData = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
    var test = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    test.Add("x", "y");
    posData.Add(test);

    // call the Where function
    var filteredList = posData.Where(x => MyFilter(x)).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(filteredList.Count); // outputs "1"
}

static bool MyFilter(Dictionary<string,string> dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("hello"); // outputs "hello"
    return dict["x"] == "y";
}
```